# MySQL - count records and list people

Tags: mysql, database

I have table with results:

```
date        | user_id | content
-----------------------------------------
2017-01-14  | 1       | lorem
2017-01-02  | 2       | dsfdf
2017-01-02  | 1       | asfds dsfsda
2017-01-27  | 3       | sdfdfds fsdf
```

And I want count row for all users and receive result like this:

```
user_id     | count
-----------------------------------------
1           | 2
2           | 1
3           | 1
```

I try:

```
select distinct(user_id), count(*) from aso_repairs where date like '2017-01-%'
```

But this don't work ;-( Any help?

Comment: Incidentally, `date >= '2017-01-01' AND date < '2017-02-01'` will be faster.

Answer (score 1):

use the GROUP BY clause:

```
SELECT 
    user_id, 
    count(user_id) 
FROM aso_repairs 
WHERE 
    date LIKE '2017-01-%' 
GROUP BY user_id
```

You shouldn't use `count(*)`, at least in MySQL 3.23 this is far more expensive than `count(somecolumn)` although it yields the same result.

Comment: "MySQL 3.23"? really? :-)

Comment: @PaulSpiegel The last version of MySQL I was really proficient in.

Answer (score 0):

Add the missing group by clause:

```
SELECT 
    user_id, COUNT(*)
FROM
    aso_repairs
WHERE
    date LIKE '2017-01-%'
GROUP BY user_id;
```

Also, the `like` operator won't let you use any index if there was one on the date column. Consider providing the actual date boundaries:

```
SELECT 
    user_id, COUNT(*)
FROM
    aso_repairs
WHERE
    date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-31'
GROUP BY user_id;
```